# HTML Characters parsing in PHP; backslash break

Tags: php, html, backslash

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    Player.embed("ID", {soundFile: "http://yoursite.com/path/to/mp3_file.mp3"});  
    </script>
```

This is the snippet I need to parse in PHP. What characters do I need to use the backslash break on?

```
<script type=\"text\/javascript\">Player\.embed\(\"$2$3$4\"\, \{soundFile\: \"http://$2$3$4/$5\"\}\);  
    <\/script>
```

Comment: Why not just echo or print it? Or use it outside of PHP tags?

Comment: i need to parse it thru php in order to pick up the variables

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on your scenario?

Comment: $2$3$4 there variables are coming out of the DB, the php retrieves them and inserts in the HTML....so the HTML must be readable by PHP, some characters mean differently to HTML and PHP eg "

Comment: Check out (json_encode)[php.net/json_encode] use it to echo out your variables. Stupid links... you get the idea

Comment: Show your actual usage, it is hard to say as is.

Comment: i just need to know which HTML characters need to be kept the same in case PHP interpretes them as something else LOL

Comment: Show your code. There are many ways to use the posted snippet. Some of them require escaping, others do not.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
 string addslashes ( string $str )
```

Returns a string with backslashes before characters that need to be escaped. These characters are single quote ('), double quote ("), backslash (\) and NUL (the NULL byte).

This source goes into it: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php 
and this one: 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_addslashes.asp
From the 2nd source, the addition of escape characters can be used to prepare a string for storage in a database and database queries.

-

**Note: PHP runs addslashes() on all GET, POST, and COOKIE data by default**, so you don't want to do it again and get double the escape slashes.

There's also a stripslashes() function for when it you need to undo it.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: .. @Ollie - was this what you needed?